# C# - HttpWebRequest POST (Login to Facebook)

Tags: c#, facebook, post, authentication, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to login to Facebook in my program and parse some information from there (like name, profile pic, etc).

I'm getting redirected back to Facebook's main page everytime I execute the code below.

```
string email = "email";
string pw = "pw";
string PostData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", email, pw);

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("");
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = PostData.Length;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(PostData);
req.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);

HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Stream datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader.ReadToEnd();

foreach (Cookie cookies in webResp.Cookies)
{
    MessageBox.Show(cookies.Name + "   " + cookies.Value);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated, many thanks! :)

edit:
I found out how to do it shortly after I posted.

Facebook sends a cookie everytime you visit it to see if you have cookies enabled, what I did was send a request to the login page of Facebook to get the cookies, then send another with the POST data. It worked this way and I successfully logged in.

Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Have you read up on the Facebook API http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/  or  http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is against the Facebook terms of service.

Comment: I often have to use the webrwser control instead of the HttpWebRequest because of this type of reasons. This question tough me something new... Plus even though it is agains facebook terms of service it could be used for ethical stuff....

Answer (score 34):

I'm glad you found your answer, I could login facebook using `HttpWebRequest` too, just like you said.. Here's an acceptable workaround:

**First *request*:** Get the cookies.

```cs
 CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com); 
 request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
 //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 cookies = response.Cookies;
```

**Second *request*:** POST the form data and recover the cookies from the first request..

```cs
 string getUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
 string postData = String.Format("email={0}&pass={1}", "value1", "value2");
 HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
 getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
 getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
 getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
 getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
 getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
 getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
 getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
 getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;   
 Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
 newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
 newStream.Close();

 HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
 {
   string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();               
 }
```

This is one of lots ways that works with `HttpWebRequest`, also if you prefer using WebBrowser, it works acceptable using the following:

```cs
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1", "",byteArray, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

What I just realized is that it doesn't work with the `InternetSetCookie` maybe the reason is because Cookies returned from Facebook have the "HttpOnly" attribute (true), and it can't be accessible by client-side script.

Comment: Excellent! That was what I was looking for. Nice, clean, complete example. Great, thx u very much.

Comment: You're welcome! but remember this is against FB Terms Of Service, since we do it for education purposes only, just use it wisely! Cheers @patryk.beza

Comment: well, it's working but my problem is what happens if i want to surf after getting the cookies (i mean after login) ?

Comment: didn't work. I got a page saying cookie files are needed

Comment: didn't work, cookie files are needed error. How to solve?

Comment: Hi, it's been quite a while since this code was posted, I'm sure fb have changed its site in these 3-4 years.

Comment: @WhySoSerious - perhaps you have some working C# example?

Comment: @FrenkyB no mate, sorry for that. I haven't touch C# in ages, I've been making a living with Laravel and web applications lately.

Comment: You missed a `"`

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is easier to use web browser and you can run that browser hidden in the background. Later you can get the inner html or perhaps download an image. Whatever you need to do. Here is an example using windows forms.

Create a new win forms application, add a button and paste that code inside. do not add anything else it should work...

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = "Your email";
    string password = "your password";

    // create a new browser
    WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
    w.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(w); // you may add the controll to your windows forms if  you want to see what is going on
    // latter you may not chose to add the browser or you can even set it to invisible... 


    // navigate to facebook
    w.Navigate(@"http://www.facebook.com/");

    // wait a little
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }


    HtmlElement temp=null;

    // while we find an element by id named email
    while (temp == null)
    {
        temp = w.Document.GetElementById("email");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }

    // once we find it place the value
    temp.SetAttribute("value", email);


    temp = null;
    // wiat till element with id pass exists
    while (temp == null)
    {
        temp = w.Document.GetElementById("pass");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }
    // once it exist set it value equal to passowrd
    temp.SetAttribute("value", password);

    // if you already found the last fields the button should also be there...

    var inputs = w.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

    int counter = 0;
    bool enableClick = false;

    // iterate through all the inputs in the document
    foreach (HtmlElement btn in inputs)
    {

        try
        {
            var att = btn.GetAttribute("tabindex");
            var name = btn.GetAttribute("id");

            if (enableClick)// button to submit always has a differnt id. it should be after password textbox
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("click");
                counter++;
            }

            if (name.ToUpper().Contains("PASS") || att=="4") 
            {
                enableClick = true;  // button should be next to the password input                    
            }

            // try a max of 5 times
            if (counter > 5)
                break;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Facebook has an API for a reason scraping HTML is hardly a decent proposal for what the question proposes.

Comment: I stated that the solution was not the best one in my response. My solution works. I am sure there will be better solutions but i dont think I deserve the -1 for a working solution.

Comment: Kk sorry about that. It might take time to learn the api. I am sure it is not complicated. I will look forward to the answer to this question...

Comment: Figured out how to do it (on first post). I know that using a webbrowser will make the job easier, but it's too bulky for me (~50k mem usage). I've already done this once using a WB anyway..

still, thanks! :)

Comment: @Lloyd try getting information like MemberCount using facebook API and then you might change your idea!

Answer (score -1):

```
webbrowser1.navigate("www.facebook.com");
webbrowser1.GetElementByiId("email").value="your mail ID";
webbrowser1.GetElementByiId("pass").value="password";
HtmlElement form = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("FormID");
if (form != null)
form.InvokeMember("submit");
```

Comment: Could you please add a comment that points out why you think your code is a solution to this issue?

Comment: there is no comment and this is just a way to fill the form automatically.