# Infinite cycle in login function (CookieCollection)

Tags: c#, post, authentication

The following function is wrote in C#, and it's used for logging in to a website (using POST Method and setting up Cookies).

The problem is that if my first login with bad username or password, I cannot log in again until i run the program again. The function is executed once, and if the login information is wrong, it ends after few minutes with this error:

```
Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); // open connection
```

**WebException was unhandled by user code:
timeout expired**

I would like to ask for a little help to find out what is wrong. In my opinion, the mistake could be in the use of CookieCollection - I would like to delete all existing cookies in case of unsuccessful login, but I cannot figure it out. I'm using this solution:

```cs
private bool Login(string name, string password) 
   { 
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.../login-page/"); 
       request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 
       request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); 
       //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request.. 
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
       cookies = response.Cookies; 

       string sourceCode; 
       string getUrl = "http://.../login/"; 
       string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", name, password); 
       HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl); 
       getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 
       getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request 
       getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post; 
       getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"; 
       getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true; 
       getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11; 
       getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true; 
       getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 

       byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData); 
       getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; 
       Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); // open connection 
       newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  // Send the data. 
       newStream.Close(); 

       HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse(); 
       cookies = getResponse.Cookies; 
       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream())) 
       { 
           sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
       } 

       if (sourceCode.Contains("<div id='login'>Přihlášení se zdařilo</div>")) 
       { 
           return true; 
       } 
       return false; 
   }
```

Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542205/2715725

I would really appreciate any kind of help. I'm not that into C# and I have problems to put this kind of code together. I have been trying to solve this for days, but even Google haven't helped me, I was looking for the solutin everywhere  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **PROBLEM SOLVED**

I added this into my function:

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
response.Close();
getRequest.KeepAlive = false;
getResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fault most likely lies in the external site to which you are posting the username and password. Are you sure it displays that exact message both when you authenticate correctly the first time, and when you manage to authenticate after a failed logon? Try both actions directly on that site to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function:

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
response.Close();
getRequest.KeepAlive = false;
getResponse.Close();
```