# Passing pameters from Desktop application to aspx page with url

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one help me on how to pass parameters along with url, that redirects me to a web page. I have a desktop application. I have a button, once the button is clicked, I need to formulate the url and keyvalue pairs and invoke the webpage. 
 Im using below code to pass parameters with URL, to open it on the web browser, but I am unabe to render page on the browser.

```
string URI = "http://localhost:3457/HiddenPageToByPassLogin.aspx";
string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-   urlencoded";

string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI,myParameters);
}
```

Can anyone explain me why I am unable to do so?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want to open browser with website ?

Comment: Hi kaushik, Yes i need to open a webpage on browser.

Comment: Do you need to open the website in a browser, or do you need to send a request and receive a response in the console session?

Comment: I bet you don't try google it before asking on SO.

Comment: Hi maniak1982, Yes I want to open webpage on the browser.

Comment: Hi sasjag, I have several methods, but Im not understanding on how to invoke the url with parameters on browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

You can pass data in query string as well

Another Way

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com/");
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: `ieplorer.exe` ? Seriously ? :p

Comment: I have used this method, can you help me to pass parameters with this url?

Comment: Hi Kaushik, I want to use POST method, as I will be passing credentials.

Comment: @Nik i m not sure about that But this answer may help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425593/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-post-login-to-facebook

Comment: Ok @Kaushik, Let me check. Thank you.

Comment: @Nik If you simply needs to post data you can do using WebClient as well

Comment: Yes Im trying with webclient, then to Im stuck with how the webpage is going to be opened on browser

Comment: @Nik using webclient u can not open page in web browser

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters by using the query string eg.

http://www.somesite.com?param1=123&param2=abc

See also [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: Hi, I want to hide the parameters being sent.

Comment: Assuming your are posting to a form then you can do it this way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: we would need to see the contents of the web page

Comment: i get this error msg The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Hi @TheEdge, please see my post. I have pasted code