# C# - Facebook Login HttpWebRequest POST

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, httprequest

I tried create login method from this tutorial [C# - HttpWebRequest POST (Login to Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425593/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-post-login-to-facebook). But it's not respond coockies so I'm still not signed. There is new way to do this?

Comment: You are not supposed to login to Facebook using any such automated tools, and Facebook is actively taking measures against it. If you want to interact with Facebook – use their API.

Answer (score 0):

Danny, these question which you mentioned is old, it was asked 4 years ago and a lot of has changed in Facebook.

As @CBroe said, Facebook is trying to block every activity apart from their API.

Check this documentation [FB Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) there is solution to your problem.