# Send an HTTP Post request to a website that Requires a Login C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am trying to send a POST request to sites like Instagram and Facebook, which require you to login. I was wondering how i would go about sending the request as an actual Browser would. I have tried working with the Web Browser control in Windows Forms,I can load and log into the site, but I don't know how to send a POST request from the browser, or take the authentication, cookies, i really don't know what i need. Any help in pointing me in the right direction or perhaps explaining what i need to add to a HttpWebRequest or send through the WebBrowser control would be greatly Appreciated.

I'd provide code but as nothing has worked i don't see it helping much.

Comment: There is no generic answer since the steps depend on the actual site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - HttpWebRequest POST (Login to Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425593/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-post-login-to-facebook)